# Is "missed" or "miss" correct here?

Tags: word-choice, tense

> Though I miss the jump into my teammates’ arms, I continue dancing.

OR

> Though I missed the jump into my teammates’ arms, I continue dancing.

Comment: Is there a choice (C)?

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated too! These aren't the only two choices

Comment: Although I missed the jump into my team-mates arms, I _continued_ dancing. The tenses did not agree...unless this is a "stream-of-consciousness" thing.

Comment: Would that still be correct if I'm trying to make it present-tense?

Comment: It's style...there is no right or wrong. Either could work.

Comment: As it currently stands, this cannot be answered. Please clarify what you want to say. Specifically, when does each event occur? If this is an extract, try including some surrounding text. If this is homework, include your interpretations and research.

Answer (score 1):

Either could be correct.  "Miss" is present tense, while "missed" is past, but "continue" is present tense.  So it depends what happened in the past and what is still happening now.

For added confusion, "miss" has several different meanings.  One is "fail to hit, reach, or come into contact with", while another is "notice the loss or absence of" (definitions from Google dictionary).